# Can I Search an entity reference with search api db?

Tags: views, search

I am using the search api database backend together with a views (with exposed fulltext search field). I want to show a 'related field' that is related to a content type that is being indexed. When the entity reference field only holds 1 value, all is fine.

But when it holds unlimited values (in the field settings) it no longer works in the view :-(

Does search api db have a limitation on indexing multivalued fields?

**UPDATE**

My content types are as follows:

- Content type a

  - Field_a = text
  - Field_b = entity ref to content type b (allowed values unlimited!)
- Content type b

  - Field 1 = text
  - Field 2 = text

I have indexed all fields above and added the related fields 1 and 2 to my search index as related fields.

Then when i create a view that shows the indexed nodes for content type a, and want to show field 2's information of the node that is referenced it only works when field b is set to allowed values: 1

Comment: Guardian, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

SearchAPI does have this limitation: Note: This is a multi-valued relationship, which is currently not supported. Only the first related entity will be shown.

Here is the issue about this. https://www.drupal.org/node/1378656

Answer (score -1):

> Does search api db have a limitation on indexing multivalued fields?

**NO**

Search Api DB & Solr allows you to indexing multivalued fields. You probably did not see the changes because you did not re-index your index.

**Edit:** To answer your question base on the comment below. My answer still **NO** does not have limitation on indexing entity reference.

> Can I Search an entity reference with search api db?

**Yes**

And here is an article that [wunderkraut posted based on Entity Reference.](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/overview-of-entity-reference/2011-10-11)

> **Benefits of Entity Reference:** Can reference any type of entity. Easy
>   to implement – follows same patterns as Node/User reference. Has Views
>   integration, even for reverse relationships. Has Entity API
>   integration, **so it works well with Search API** and Rules.

Comment: Dear Darol, I tried to re-index several times, without any luck...

Comment: Just to understand your question a little bit better. Are you trying to have multiple search fields ? And one is from the search api and the another one is not ?

Comment: Dear Darol, No that is not the case. I have an entity reference field on my content type that contains multiple values. I now want to be able to search a field from one of the referenced nodes

Comment: I have update my question.

Comment: Darol, i have updated the question with an example. Hope tis is more clear. I saw the article as well, but i dont think it has the answer to my question. Thanks so much!